# ✔ Checkmark selected row in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am an iOS development newbie. I want to add a checkmark to my `UITableViewCell` when it is selected. The checkmark should be removed when another row is selected. How would I do this?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Do not use `[tableview reloadData];`  // its a hammer.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: What if I want only the checkmark and want to deselect the row after a selection?

Comment: it selecting same index row in every section @Ujwal Manjunath

Comment: -(void)reloadData should be relatively cheap, according to the docs. Nevertheless, this is more semantically pleasing.

Comment: Why shouldn't you use '[tableview reloadData]'? I want to use multiselect in my tableview. I am using the the objects received from the server to set the checkmark in my tableview cell. Once, I do that, I save the check objects in a global array. However, when I use that array to compare inside my 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' method to see if the indexpath matches to this object inside my global array. I am not able to find it. I think its the [tableView reloadData]. What do you think?Please advice.

Comment: The above answers not work if you reused the cell for large number of data. On scroll you can see repeated checkmark. Check my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982944/checkmark-selected-row-in-uitableviewcell/44539239#44539239

Answer (score 81):

In your UITableViewDatasource method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil )
    {
        cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if ([indexPath compare:self.lastIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

// UITableView Delegate Method
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

And lastIndexPath is a `property(strong)  NSIndexPath* lastIndexPath;`

Answer (score 21):

I found that reloading the data interrupts the deselect animation in an ugly way.

This Swift implementation cleanly adds/removes checkmarks and deselects the row:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if self.lastSelection != nil {
        self.myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.lastSelection)?.accessoryType = .None
    }

    self.myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

    self.lastSelection = indexPath

    self.myTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

where `lastSelection` is declared as `var lastSelection: NSIndexPath!`

No extra activity in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` needed. Shouldn't be hard to replicate in Obj-C.

Answer (score 13):

To set a checkmark:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = ...;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

To select/deselect a cell:

```
[cell setSelected:TRUE animated:TRUE]; // select
[cell setSelected:FALSE animated:TRUE]; // deselect
```

To deselect the previous cell use a NSIndexPath *lastSelected ivar to track the last selected cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   if (self.lastSelected==indexPath) return; // nothing to do

   // deselect old
   UITableViewCell *old = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastSelected];
   old.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   [old setSelected:FALSE animated:TRUE];

   // select new
   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   [cell setSelected:TRUE animated:TRUE];

   // keep track of the last selected cell
   self.lastSelected = indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I think it's cleaner to set the accessory within your custom UITableViewCell implementation. In swift, I have used:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
}
```

Comment: This Answer is Criminally underrated.

Answer (score 9):

**Update Swift 4**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        if selectedData.contains(dataArray[indexPath.row]) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if selectedData.contains(dataArray[indexPath.row]) {
            selectedData.removeLast()
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        }else {
            selectedData.removeAll()
            selectedData.append(dataArray[indexPath.row])
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        print(selectedData)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }

}
```

based on dataArray table view formed.. similarly, I took an empty array, and whenever the user taps on a cell, based on indexValue of from dataArray I stored that object in selectedDataArray

As for the question its like... A question has multiple options(Answers), But at finally only one or none answer will be a result

[image]

Likewise, only one cell should show checkmark and remaining cells should be in unselected... it some case u can deselect your answer... I hope this is the best answer to this question

[image]

Comment: This first line ist still not formated as code. Use interpunctation!

Answer (score 6):

Using Swift 4.2 and swift 5
Working code of check mark for only selected row in TableView

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //print(self.coloursArray[indexPath.row])

     self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are in a class that inherits from `UITableViewController`, this does the trick in Swift 3:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Add a visual cue to indicate that the cell was selected.
    self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    // Invoked so we can prepare for a change in selection.
    // Remove previous selection, if any.
    if let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        // Note: Programmatically deslecting does NOT invoke tableView(:didSelectRowAt:), so no risk of infinite loop.
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndex, animated: false)
        // Remove the visual selection indication.
        self.tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndex)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answers not work if you reused the cell for large number of data. On scroll you can see repeated checkmark. To avoid use below steps:

1. declare on variable :
   var indexNumber:NSInteger = -1
2. Add below code in cellforRowAtIndexPath:

   ```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{         
          if indexNumber == indexPath.row{
              cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
          }else{
              cell.accessoryType = .none
          }
   }
   ```
3. And in didselectAtIndexpath add below code:

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark    
indexNumber = indexPath.row
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you could do it. one is without multiple 
     selections and another is with multiple selections.

```
// Table View Controller -- without Multiple Selection

// Step 1

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image == UIImage(systemName:"checkmark.circle")) {
         tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"circle")
    } else {
         tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"checkmark.circle")
    }
}

//Step 2

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = employeeValues[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"circle")

    return cell
}

//  Table View Controller -- with Multiple Selection

@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = employeeValues[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"circle")

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark

    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"checkmark.circle")

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"circle")  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

small typo

```
// deselect old
UITableViewCell *old = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastSelected];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
[cell setSelected:FALSE animated:TRUE];
```

should read

```
// deselect old
UITableViewCell *old = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastSelected];
old.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
[old setSelected:FALSE animated:TRUE];
```

and also in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == [previouslySelected intValue])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        selectedIndex = indexPath;
        [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

where **previouslySelected** is your local ivar, etc. that way if you reload with a selected index it also gets deselected when you flick through the possible selections.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to face this problem from other direction. Put all work on internal UIKit mechanisms and move implementation to UITableViewCell:

```
@implementation MYTableViewCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    self.accessoryType = selected ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Check or Uncheck a cell 
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method when select any row to Show CheckMark and Select checkmark row for hide CheckMark.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:true];
    NSLog(@"touch");

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 4 in case you need.

```
var lastSelection: NSIndexPath!
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    //CHECK MARK THE CELL
    if self.lastSelection != nil {
        self.tableView.cellForRow(at: self.lastSelection as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }

    self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

    self.lastSelection = indexPath as NSIndexPath

    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
    var selectedIndex: IndexPath!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndex != nil {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndex)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    selectedIndex = indexPath
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The upper mentioned code only works with the **single selection**.This following code will surely works for **multiple selections**.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    arrSelectionStatus =[NSMutableArray array]; //arrSelectionStatus holds the cell selection status 
    for (int i=0; i<arrElements.count; i++) { //arrElements holds those elements which will be populated in tableview
        [arrSelectionStatus addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[arrElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([[arrSelectionStatus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == YES)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    [arrSelectionStatus replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    [arrSelectionStatus replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a selected cell(with the check mark is selected again), just remove the selection.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    BOOL isSelected = ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType ==  UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);
    if(isSelected){
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; //this won't trigger the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath, but it's always a good idea to remove the selection
    }else{
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

**Bonus:**

Use `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` for detecting indexPath for the selected cell